# AngularJS Jasmine testing get-request

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a factory to execute a get request, I'd like to test. Unfortunately the karma test tells me that there is not response defined at $httpBackend.

AngularJs 1.2.14,
Jasmine 2.0,
Karma 0.12.0

Here's my module I'd like to test:

```
var appFactory = angular.module('appFactory', []);

appFactory.factory('boxListService', function($http){
    return{
        getList: function(){
            return $http.get('/boxlist').then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My test is this:

```
describe('Module-Test', function() {

    beforeEach(module('appFactory'));

     it('should call $http.get in getList', inject(function (boxListService, $httpBackend){
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/boxlist');
        boxListService.getList();
        $httpBackend.flush();
      }));
});
```

Message:

```
Error: No response defined !
at $httpBackend (D:/nodeJS/host/test_app/src/public/js/libs/angular/angular-mock.js:1206:13)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to define the expected response, as well as the expected request. It will have the form:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/boxlist').respond(HTTP_STATUS_CODE, EXPECTED_RESPONSE);
```

HTTP_STATUS_CODE is an integer.
EXPECTED_RESPONSE is the value to be returned (it's often an Object Literal).

You may define only one of them.

Look at [ngMock httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend) documentation for more information.

Comment: I looked at this about 5 times before I realized that the response also needs to be declared on the expectGET.  I was under the impression that the whenGET was the only place where it was necessary to declare the response.  Is is safe to say that one must declare a response on both the whenGET and expectGET?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps and because it happened to me, although it is not the exact case of the question. I had these two lines:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(myService.serviceURL).respond(myMock);
$httpBackend.expectGET(myService.serviceURL);
```

With `when` I wanted to define what to response when calling the service and with `expect` I wanted to check that the method was called.

This doesn't work (although sometimes it does, I don't know why). I guess somehow `expect` is overriding `when` and therefore I got

> Error: No response defined !

The solution was to remove the `when` clause and add `respond()` to `expect`

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(myService.serviceURL).respond(myMock);
```

I don't know why the framework behaves that way. If someone knows it would be nice that you explain it here to improve the answer